How to link doctest with Botan
I am having difficulty in linking Botan with doctest.
I followed the CLion documentation and I have this:
\PROJECT
  |____ \cmake
  |        |____ FindBotan.cmake <== My Botan CMake
  |                
  |____ \doc
  |       |_____ \html
  |       |_____ \latex
  |       |_____ Doxyfile
  |
  |____ \include
  |       |_____ File1.h
  |       |_____ File2.h
  |       |_____ File3.h
  |       |_____ File4.h
  |       |_____ File5.h
  |____ \src
  |       |_____ File1.cpp
  |       |_____ File2.cpp
  |       |_____ File3.cpp
  |       |_____ File4.cpp
  |       |_____ File5.cpp
  |       |_____ main.cpp
  |____ \test
  |       |_____ doctest.h <== From the GitHub project
  |       |_____ CMakeLists.txt <== doctest CMAKE
  |       |_____ Test1Test.cpp <== First test
  |       |_____ Test2Test.cpp <== Second test
  |____ CMakeLists.txt <== Root cmake

My FindBotan.cmake looks like this:
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

if (NOT TARGET Botan::Botan)
    pkg_check_modules(Botan QUIET IMPORTED_TARGET botan-3)
    if (TARGET PkgConfig::Botan)
        add_library(Botan::Botan ALIAS PkgConfig::Botan)
    endif ()
endif ()

if (NOT TARGET Botan::Botan)
    find_path(Botan_INCLUDE_DIRS NAMES botan/botan.h
              PATH_SUFFIXES botan-3
              DOC "The Botan include directory")

    find_library(Botan_LIBRARIES NAMES botan botan-3
                 DOC "The Botan library")

    mark_as_advanced(Botan_INCLUDE_DIRS Botan_LIBRARIES)

    add_library(Botan::Botan IMPORTED UNKNOWN)
    set_target_properties(
            Botan::Botan
            PROPERTIES
            IMPORTED_LOCATION "${Botan_LIBRARIES}"
            INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${Botan_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
    )
endif ()

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(
        Botan
        REQUIRED_VARS Botan_LIBRARIES Botan_INCLUDE_DIRS
)

My CMakeLists.txt inside my test folder looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(test_run Test1Test.cpp Test2Test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_run PRIVATE Botan::Botan)
find_package(Botan REQUIRED)

My root CMakeLists.txt looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(PROJECT)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include_directories(*)

add_executable(PROJECT
               src/main.cpp
               src/File1.cpp
               include/File1.h
               src/File2.cpp
               include/File2.h
               src/File3.cpp
               include/File3.h
               src/File4.cpp
               include/File4.h
               src/File5.cpp
               include/File5.h
)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(Botan REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(PROJECT PRIVATE Botan::Botan)

add_subdirectory(test)

I have tried to change the test/CMakeLists.txt to this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(test_run Test1Test.cpp Test2Test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_run include)
find_package(Botan REQUIRED)

which produces this error when I run my tests:
fatal error: botan/rsa.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <botan/rsa.h>

I have tried to include both the include folder and PRIVATE Botan::Botan to test/CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(test_run Test1Test.cpp Test2Test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_run PRIVATE Botan::Botan include)
find_package(Botan REQUIRED)

which produces this error when I run my tests:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -linclude: No such file or directory

Please let me know if you know what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you.
